# multiple port forwarding

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding

Here is my configuration

- HostA (client):

  ```
  ssh -fTN -L 7878:127.0.0.1:8989 jfroot@10.162.241.105
  https_proxy=http://localhost:7878
  http_proxy=http://localhost:7878
  ```
- HostB (forwarding server)

  ```
  IP: 10.162.241.105
  ssh -fTN -L 9898:localhost:3129 root@10.162.241.112
  forward-ports:
      port=8989:proto=tcp:toport=9898:toaddr=
  ```
- HostC (server): HostC has proxy defined on port 3129

  ```
  IP: 10.162.241.112
  ```

What I want to achieve is: I want to run apt update on HostA but it doesn't work.

HostA should connect to HostB on port 8989. Firewalld of HostB should forward traffic from 9898 to 8989.

Comment: Is 10.162.241.105 = HostB? Similarly is 10.162.241.112 = HostC? You omitted to tie names to addresses :-)

Comment: HostA is expecting to talk on port 8989 but your HostB is listening on 9898. Is the aim to get HostA to connect to the proxy on HostC via an ssh tunnel on HostB? If so, there's definitely other questions on the site that address this tunnelling approach

Comment: Yes this is the aim. So how to properly add firewalld port forward?